# How to build a HTML/CSS table with scrollable lines?

Tags: html, css

Using pure CSS/HTML, I'm trying to build a table that vertically scrolls lines only (tbody) when there is no vertical space. My table has a single column.

Here is my code:

```css
.dialog_table {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.dialog_thead {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: purple;
}

.dialog_tbody {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.dialog_th {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.dialog_td {
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dialog_tbody .dialog_tr:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table class="dialog_table">
  <thead class="dialog_thead">
    <td class="dialog_th">COLUMN 1</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="dialog_tbody">
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 16</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

With the above code, I'm getting 2 problems: an extra grid is added to the right side of the table and there is no scrollable lines - `overflow-y: scroll` seems not to be working. What can I try next?

Comment: What do you mean by lines — lines of text? And what do you mean by "when there is no vertical space"?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position:sticky`:

```css
.dialog_table {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.dialog_thead {
  position:sticky; top:0;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: purple;
}

.dialog_tbody {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.dialog_th {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.dialog_td {
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dialog_tbody .dialog_tr:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table class="dialog_table">
  <thead class="dialog_thead">
    <td class="dialog_th">COLUMN 1</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="dialog_tbody">
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dialog_tbody">
      <td class="dialog_td">DATA 16</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove
**display: block;**
from **.dialog_table**

An element that has the display property set to block starts on a new line and takes up the available screen width.